# Causaltune error (fit() missing 2 required positional arguments)

Tags: causality, causal-inference, dowhy

I am trying to rebuild [Random assignment, binary CATE example](https://github.com/py-why/causaltune/blob/main/notebooks/Random%20assignment%2C%20binary%20CATE%20example.ipynb) for my dataset. Coming to `ct.fit(data=cd, outcome=cd.outcomes[0])` I get the error `TypeError: fit() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'treatment_name' and 'outcome_name'`

Everything before that runs without any problems

This is the codeblock:

```
ct = CausalTune(
    estimator_list=estimator_list,
    metric=metric,
    verbose=0,
    components_verbose=0,
    time_budget=time_budget,
    components_time_budget=components_time_budget,
    train_size=train_size
)


# run causaltune
ct.fit(data=cd, outcome=cd.outcomes[0])

print('---------------------')
# return best estimator
print(f"Best estimator: {ct.best_estimator}")
# config of best estimator:
print(f"Best config: {ct.best_config}")
# best score:
print(f"Best score: {ct.best_score}")
```

After preprocessing my dataset looks like this: (with successful being the outcome and treatment being the treatment)

| treatment | successful | random | NumberOfTerms | MonthlyCost | CreditScore | OfferedAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0.0 | 22.0 | 241.279999 | 0.0 | 5000.0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0.0 | 22.0 | 241.279999 | 0.0 | 5000.0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1.0 | 22.0 | 241.279999 | 0.0 | 5000.0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1.0 | 22.0 | 241.279999 | 0.0 | 5000.0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1.0 | 22.0 | 241.279999 | 0.0 | 5000.0 |

Does anyone know of a solution?

I do not know why this error occurs, I tried using different estimators but that does not fix the issue. Printing `cd.outcomes[0]` gives `successful` so the error does not seem to lie there.